# Want to display list data in html table C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

[enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkgcW.png)

I want to add list data in the html Table.
The list data can be various, so table rows were dynamic and if List size increase user can use paging in table to move next...

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Date1.Add(sdr["Date"].ToString());
                        Time.Add(sdr["Time"].ToString());
                        Event.Add(sdr["Event"].ToString());
                        Venue.Add(sdr["Venue"].ToString());
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Date1.Count; i++) {

            string Date11 = Date1[i];
            string Time1 = Time[i];
            string Event1 = Event[i];
            string Venue1 = Venue[i];
            if(Venue1.Contains(country) || Venue1.Contains(Code[0]))
            {
                Result.Add( Date11 + " " + Time1 + " " + Event1 + " " + Venue1);

            }

        }
```

Can someone kindly give me code/hint which can i use in my Project. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Why don't you use the GridView control?The underlying HTML generated by the GridView control is a HTML table and it supports paging

Answer (score 0):

The example below takes care of the following requirements which you've listed in the question:

1. Generates an HTML table containing your data
2. Has paging functionality
3. Supports dynamic columns

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        gvEvents.DataSource = this.GetEvents();
        gvEvents.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataTable GetEvents()
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 Date,Time,Event,Venue FROM Event",connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(table);

            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    int rows = table.Rows.Count;//Place breakpoint to make sure table has rows

    return table;
}

protected void gvEvents_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvEvents.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvEvents.DataSource = this.GetEvents();
    gvEvents.DataBind();
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEvents" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="gvEvents_PageIndexChanging">
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying dynamic column data in gridview control]

Comment: Your answer was almost correct Denis but i want to populate mn List Data in Html table before that m doing like that you explain to mee\

Comment: i have a search of venue it venue can b written in different ways country names or stadium name so i here was important that too compare the database results with my venues list

Comment: Please upvote or mark as answered if my answer helped you